# Búsqueda de usuarios en Ion Auth

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Boton de busqueda usuarios en ion_auth.

Éste es mi código en el modelo

```
    public function buscar($bus,$id=FALSE)
    {

    $id || $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('groups g'); 
    $this->db->join('users_groups f','g.id=f.group_id');
    $this->db->join('users u','u.id=f.user_id');
    $this->db->where('g.id=f.group_id');
    $this->db->where('f.user_id=u.id');
    $this->db->where('u.id',$id);
    if($bus){
    $this->db->like('u.first_name',$bus);
    }        
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }
```

y el código en el controlador:

```
function index2() {

  //$data['departamento']=$this->contar_resultados_busqueda_ctrl();
  if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
    //redirect them to the login page
    redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
  } elseif (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
    redirect('admin/no_permission', 'refresh');
  } else {
    $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
   //inicio paginacion
   $this->data['title'] = 'Paginacion_ci';
   $pages=9; //Número de registros mostrados por páginas
   $this->load->library('pagination'); //Cargamos la librería de paginación
   $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/auth/index2/pagina/'; //     parametro base de la aplicación, si tenemos un .htaccess nos evitamos el index.php
   $config['total_rows'] = $this->ion_auth->filas_default();//calcula el número de filas 

   $config['per_page'] = $pages; //Número de registros mostrados por páginas
   $config['num_links'] = 10; //Número de links mostrados en la paginación
   $config['first_link'] = 'Primera';//primer link
   $config['last_link'] = 'Última';//último link
   $config["uri_segment"] = 4;//el segmento de la paginación
   $config['next_link'] = 'Siguiente';//siguiente link
   $config['prev_link'] = 'Anterior';//anterior link
   $this->pagination->initialize($config); //inicializamos la paginación 
   // $data["provincias"] = $this->model_provincia->total_paginados_depto($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3),$nombre_depto); 

   $resultados = $this->ion_auth->users2($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4)); 
   $this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users2($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4)); 
   foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user) {
     $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();
   }
   /*conservar lugar*/
   $array_msg = array('descripcion'=>$this->input->post('descripcion'),'cargo'=>$this->input->post('cargo'), 'departamento'=>$this->input->post('departamento'));
   $breadcrumb = array(
      "Inicio" => "auth/index2/pagina/".$this->uri->segment(4),
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata('url_actual',$breadcrumb);
   $ses=$this->session->userdata('url_actual');
   /*conservar lugar*/
   //fin paginacion
   //envíamos los datos al modelo para hacer la búsqueda
   //$resultados = $this->model_buscadorempleo->busqueda_default($campos);
  }    
  if($_POST){
    $buscar = $this->input->post('busqueda');
  }
  else
  {
    $buscar = '';
  }


  //$this->data['users2'] = $this->ion_auth->users2();
  //get this user
  /*foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user) {
    $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->buscar( $buscar);
  }*/



 /*    
 $this->data['users']= $this->ion_auth->buscar($buscar);
 );

  ;*/ 
 /*
 $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->buscar($buscar); 
 */

 foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user) {
   $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->buscar($buscar, $user->id);
 }
```

Comment: ¿Recibes algún mensaje de error? ¿Cómo no funciona?

Comment: hola, que versión de ci estas usando, el join no se maneja como tu lo estas usnado [ci documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: hola gracias por responder pero no lo que pase es que cuando hago la busqueda no desaparecen los demas usuarios solo los grupos